# Server 500 Error - https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg

Tags: google-cloud-platform, curl

I'm trying to install kubectl through my circleci workflow. This is existing code, and nothing has changed, but when trying to get the apt-key.gpg from Google, it gives me a server 500. This happens with curl, wget, and going directly in a browser.

```
wget https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg
--2023-02-26 13:40:10--  https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg
Resolving packages.cloud.google.com (packages.cloud.google.com)... 142.251.45.238
Connecting to packages.cloud.google.com (packages.cloud.google.com)|142.251.45.238|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 500 Internal Server Error
2023-02-26 13:40:10 ERROR 500: Internal Server Error.
```

Anyone have a way of getting past this? Thanks!

I've tried from within my vpc, public internet, etc, etc. wget, curl, etc

Comment: fyi for those with the same issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/116068

Comment: FYI it's already fixed!

Answer (score 1):

[The discussion at the GitHub issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/k8s.io/pull/4837#issuecomment-1446426585) suggests using `https://dl.k8s.io/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This [solution](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/issues/961#issuecomment-1446300665) worked for me :

- get the apt-key.gpg through `https://web.archive.org/web/20230223152417if_/https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg`

Comment: FYI it's already fixed!